# Problem with \expandafter and xparse tests

Tags: macros, expansion, xparse

I am trying to build with `xparse` a macro that interfaces another macro from an existing package. The latter takes an option `[d]`, which I would like to represent with a star using the `s` argument type of `xparse`.

To avoid referencing explicitly the macro from the original package, let's consider a basic macro `\Foo` which changes behavior depending on the presence of a star:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\Foo}{s}
  {\IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {foo bar}
    {foo baz}}
```

Now I would like to interface `\Foo` with the following concise implementation:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\FooInterfaceBad}{s}
  {\Foo \IfBooleanT{#1}{*}}
```

As the name suggests, this implementation does not work, which I suspect is caused by the `IfBooleanT` macro not being expanded. However, the following does not work either:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\FooInterfaceAlsoBad}{s}
  {\expandafter \Foo \IfBooleanT{#1}{*}}
```

Of course I could do it in the following way, which works:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\FooInterfaceGood}{s}
  {\IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\Foo*}
    {\Foo}}
```

However, if I add other options to `\Foo` in the future, I will need to handle each possible combination of options with a bunch of `\IfBooleanTF`, leading to exponential duplication of code. This applies directly to the situation I motivated in the beginning, where I try to interface a complex macro with many options.

Thus my question is: is there a way to make `FooInterfaceBad` work, or at least an alternative that avoids an exponential number of tests?

Here is the complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\Foo}{s}
  {\IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {foo bar}
    {foo baz}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\FooInterfaceBad}{s}
  {\Foo \IfBooleanT{#1}{*}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\FooInterfaceAlsoBad}{s}
  {\expandafter \Foo \IfBooleanT{#1}{*}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\FooInterfaceGood}{s}
  {\IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\Foo*}
    {\Foo}}

\begin{document}

\Foo*

\FooInterfaceBad*

\FooInterfaceAlsoBad*

\FooInterfaceGood*

\end{document}
```

Comment: The tests from `xparse` need more than a single expansion, so instead of doing `\expandafter\foo\IfBooleanTF{#1}{[a]}{[b]}` you should do `\IfBooleanTF{#1}{\foo[a]}{\foo[b]}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you want that `\Foo` executes `\othercommandfrompackage` and `\Foo*` instead `\othercommandfrompackage[d]`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

% this emulates the command from the package
\newcommand{\othercommandfrompackage}[1][]{%
  \if d#1%
    there was the optional argument%
  \else
    there was no optional argument%
  \fi
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\Foo}{s}{%
  \expandafter\othercommandfrompackage\expanded{\IfBooleanT{#1}{[d]}}%
}

\begin{document}

\Foo

\Foo*

\end{document}
```

[image]

With more details about the *real* problem, some better code could be written.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer, the `\expanded` macro did the trick!

Answer (score 2):

You could go for a processor that sets the argument to `*` if there was a star and leaves it empty if there was none:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\newcommand\mystarprocessor[1]
  {%
    \edef\ProcessedArgument{\IfBooleanT{#1}{*}}%
  }
\NewDocumentCommand\foo{>{\mystarprocessor}s}
  {%
    Was there a star? (#1)%
  }

\begin{document}
\foo

\foo*
\end{document}
```

Alternatively you could control the number of expansion steps with a `\romannumeral` trick. The following will expand everything until it hits a space token, which will then be gobbled (or the expansion will stop if another non-expandable token is hit):

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\newcommand\mystarprocessor[1]
  {%
    \edef\ProcessedArgument{\IfBooleanT{#1}{*}}%
  }
\NewDocumentCommand\foo{>{\mystarprocessor}s}
  {%
    Was there a star? (#1)%
  }
\NewDocumentCommand\fooexpanded{s}
  {%
    \expandafter\foo\romannumeral`\^^@\IfBooleanTF{#1}{ *}{ }%
  }

\begin{document}
\fooexpanded

\fooexpanded*
\end{document}
```

Comment: Since you like playing with `\romannumeral` (what efforts to get a `0` :-), your `\fooexpanded` (second piece of code) could be written this way using `expl3` syntax: `\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \fooexpanded { s }
  {
    \exp_after:wN \foo \exp:w \IfBooleanTF {#1} { \exp_end: * } { \exp_end: }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff` (I know you know; this is for other people passing by...).

Comment: To elaborate a bit more on the `0` (then I stop harassing you, promised), `\romannumeral\`\^^@` would be useful if we weren't able to guarantee that the next unexpandable token encountered by `\romannumeral` (after `\`\^^@`) will be a space token (e.g., a digit could lead to undesirable effects). But since here, it is quite clear that regardless of the branch taken, the next unexpandable token found by `\romannumeral` will be a space token, `\romannumeral0` would do as well, AFAICT.

Comment: @frougon if the question was using `expl3` I'd have provided code using `\exp_args_last_unbraced:Nf`. I think that it is best to provide the most stable version of `\romannumeral` expansion in answers like these and the speed gain from using `0` instead of `\`^^@` is around 0.01 ops (ca. 6% faster). I doubt that this difference is worth the reduced stability.

Comment: My comments were simple remarks, not criticisms (I gave you the first upvote here, mind you). :-) My opinion about the `\romannumeral` trick is that if one understands it, seeing that a space token is guaranteed to come out before any other 〈number〉 terminator here, shouldn't be a problem. I agree that the performance gain with `\exp:w ... \exp_end:` is negligible; that is why I didn't mention it at all. Not a big deal, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you allow an auxiliary macro, you can do:

```
\newcommand\exchange[2]{#2#1}

\NewDocumentCommand{\FooInterfaceNotSoBad}{s}
  {\IfBooleanT{#1}{\exchange{*}}\Foo}
```

You can also use `\romannumeral0`-expansion:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\FooInterfaceAlsoNotSoBad}{s}
  {\expandafter\Foo\romannumeral0\IfBooleanTF{#1}{ *}{ }}
```

Be aware that after tokenizing the control-word-token `\Foo` the reading apparatus of (La)TeX is in state S (skipping blanks) which implies that subsequent spaces occurring in the .tex-input-file are discarded instead of yielding tokens that get inserted into the token-stream while after tokenizing the catcode-12(other)-character-token `*` the reading-apparatus of (La)TeX is in state M (middle of line) which implies that subsequent spaces usually are tokenized as space-tokens that are inserted into the token-stream and in horizontal mode may yield horizontal glue. If both after `\Foo` and after `\Foo*` no more non-delimited/brace-nested arguments are to be gathered by (La)TeX, then you may wish to add `\ignorespaces` in case a star is present. If non-delimited/brace-nested arguments are to be gathered after `\Foo`/`\Foo*`, then this is not necessary as space-tokens preceding non-delimited/brace-nested arguments are always discarded by (La)TeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\Foo}{s}
  {\IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {foo bar\ignorespaces}
    {foo baz}}
\newcommand\exchange[2]{#2#1}
\NewDocumentCommand{\FooInterfaceNotSoBad}{s}
  {\IfBooleanT{#1}{\exchange{*}}\Foo}
\NewDocumentCommand{\FooInterfaceAlsoNotSoBad}{s}
  {\expandafter\Foo\romannumeral0\IfBooleanTF{#1}{ *}{ }}
% In Exol-Syntax you use ~ for denoting a space-token:
%\ExplSyntaxOn
%\NewDocumentCommand{\FooInterfaceAlsoNotSoBad}{s}
%  {\expandafter\Foo\romannumeral0\IfBooleanTF{#1}{~*}{~}}
%\ExplSyntaxOff
\NewDocumentCommand{\FooInterfaceGood}{s}
  {\IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\Foo*}
    {\Foo}}

\begin{document}

(\Foo* )

(\Foo  )

(\FooInterfaceNotSoBad* )

(\FooInterfaceNotSoBad )

(\FooInterfaceAlsoNotSoBad* )

(\FooInterfaceAlsoNotSoBad )

(\FooInterfaceGood* )

(\FooInterfaceGood )

\end{document}
```